# How to call a closure with multiple parameters from collect() method of a groovy collection?

Tags: collections, groovy, closures

Let's say I have a closure:

```
def increment = {value, step ->
   value + step 
}
```

Now I want to loop over every item of my integers collection, increment it with 5, and save new elements to a new collection:

```
def numbers = [1..10]
def biggerNumbers = numbers.collect {
      it + 5
}
```

And now I want to achieve the same result but by means of using `increment` closure. How can I do this?

Should be something like this (wrong code below):

```
def biggerNumbers = numbers.collect increment(it, 5) //what's the correct name of 'it'??
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to your problem would be nesting your call of increment in a closure:

```
def biggerNumbers = numbers.collect {increment(it, 5)}
```

If you wanted to pass a premade closure to the `collect` you should have made it compatible with `collect` - accepting a single parameter that is:

```
def incrementByFive = {it + 5}
def biggerNumbers = numbers.collect incrementByFive
```

Answer (score 10):

mojojojo has the right answer, but just thought I'd add that this looks like a good candidate for [currying](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-add-some-curry-for.html) (specifically [using `rcurry`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-new-ways-to-curry.html))

If you have:

```
def increment = {value, step ->
   value + step 
}
```

You can then curry the right-hand parameter of this function with:

```
def incrementByFive = increment.rcurry 5
```

And then, you can do:

```
def numbers = 1..10
def biggerNumbers = numbers.collect incrementByFive
```

Just thought it might be of interest ;-)

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but you've made a tiny mistake in `numbers.collect { incrementByFive it }` by instantiating a redundant closure when `numbers.collect incrementByFive` would have been enough. Things like that result in overhead, although Groovy is not about performance.

Comment: @mojojojo good catch thanks :-)  Fixed the code, as there's no point having sub-optimal examples around for people in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `[1..10]` creates a `List<IntRange>` which you are trying to increment. You should `collect` on the IntRange directly (note the lack of brackets):

```
(1..10).collect { it + 5 }
```

Or with curry:

```
def sum = { a, b -> a + b }
(1..10).collect(sum.curry(5))
```